# Why can't I copy a 7 GB file to an external USB HD with 120 GB free?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, filesystems, fat32

Yes, why can't I?

I was stashing away some old photography backup zips last night. I could copy 4 of my > 1 GB backup zips to my external USB connected hard-drive when I got the error message "Cannot copy file. Not enough free space." (sort of) for a zip of roughly 7 GB.

But there are 120 GB free. Why is this?

EDIT: Clarification - the files that I could copy was smaller than 4 GB. The failing one was 7 GB. The cause seems to be the FAT32 4 GB limit.

Comment: Consider removing irrelevant tags (backup, zip, memory) and adding tags 'filesystems', 'fat'.

Comment: Roger that, Bender!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe your External HDD is formatted as FAT? FAT-formatted drives can't see files larger than 4 GB, you'll have to reformat it as NTFS.

> The maximum possible size for a file on a FAT32 volume is 4 GB minus 1 byte (2<sup>32</sup>−1 bytes). Video applications, large databases, and some other software easily exceed this limit. Larger files require another formatting type such as NTFS.

[FAT32 @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32#FAT32)

Or you could split the zip file in two 3.5 GB parts.

Comment: That's spot on!

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the drive has been formatted with FAT32 which has a maximum file size of 4GB. See the [Wikipedia article on FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32)

Format the drive with NTFS and it should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I formatted my 8gb flash card to **exFAT** as I haven't NTFS option in "format" menu. But it works fine!