# File too large for the destination file system

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, fat32

Trying to copy an 11.3G file to a brand new 65G flash drive. Keep getting error message "the file is too large for the destination file system. It is a brand new flash drive formatted to fat32. On windows7. Any suggestions??  Thanks!

Comment: FAT32 can only handle files upto 4GB in size.  Reformat the drive as NTFS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I copy a 7 GB file to an external USB HD with 120 GB free?](http://superuser.com/questions/64858/why-cant-i-copy-a-7-gb-file-to-an-external-usb-hd-with-120-gb-free) and/or [Windows 7 says a 8.6 GB file won't fit in 14.7 GB space?](http://superuser.com/questions/617211/windows-7-says-a-8-6-gb-file-wont-fit-in-14-7-gb-space)

Comment: You would have to break the file into 3.9gb chunks.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the flash drive icon, select `Format`, and format it as `exFAT`, which does not have the 4 GB limitation.

Comment: Note that formatting deletes all contents of the flash drive

Answer (score 1):

Between exFat and NTFS, exFat is the better choice for flash drives. The exFat file system was designed for that purpose, has much less overhead and performs fewer small writes than NTFS. Another advantage is that exFat is supported by both Windows and OSx, so an exFat formatted thumb drive can help the Windows and Mac folks to get along.