# Non-sensical message moving a file to external storage

Tags: windows, memory, sd-card, usb-storage

So why is it a problem, on a Windows laptop with an external USB memory device (an ***empty*** **256 GB microSDXC** card in USB reader, shows up as D: in explorer) to try to **drag and drop a 4.86 GB file** to it from C:? Also tried cut/paste.

I get a pop-up dialog titled "Move Item"

"There is not enough space on *target_drive_name*"

4.84 GB is needed to move this item.

Delete or move files so you have enough space.

*target_drive_name*

Space free: 238 GB

Total size: 238 GB

I was able to create a text file and save it on D:.

Comment: That is definitely helpful - I never even thought about FAT formatting and the file size limitations!

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that your SDXC card is not faulty? Before retrying, I would perform one or two tests on the card:

When there are no useful data on the card, format it (with an exFAT or NTFS file system) before use. Older cards sometimes have faulty file systems you can get rid of by re-formatting.

If this does not help (or itself creates error messages), I would use a testing tool like `h2testw` to dind out what's wrong.

Comment: FAT32 IS the problem! Please read and understand https://superuser.com/questions/64858/why-cant-i-copy-a-7-gb-file-to-an-external-usb-hd-with-120-gb-free as the the question as been flagged as duplicate. Suggesting NTFS or the new exFAT (supposedly better for flash memory) is fine, never FAT32.

Comment: This is why I said FAT32+, *not* FAT32. And: I know from my camera (Canon EOS 70D) that it does store files > 4 GB on a pre-formatted SD card.

Comment: In a pre-formatted SD card with other than FAT32, likely exFAT, sure. Not in a FAT32 formatted card without either (1) reformatting it to a compatible file system or (2) using some file splitting trickery. More likely #1 because it explicitly says here https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART142743 that **"This device incorporates exFAT technology licensed from Microsoft"**. Also *support for FAT32+ and FAT16+ is limited to some versions of DR-DOS and not available in mainstream operating systems.* (from Wikipedia).

Comment: Yep, then it must be exFAT (which surprisedly makes to trouble on my Linux machine, which in turn still doesn't fully support NTFS). I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Any major Linux distro supports perfectly NTFS for decades now. exFAT support is also at the kernel level (5.x) in all current Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives, Arch/Manjaro and derivatives, etc. etc. If running older kernels then exfat-tools (or something like that) must be installed.